# single query for display two rows and assuming two table

Tags: mysql

for example this is my data

```
info
----
id   name     eating                 andSaying
---  ----     ------                ---------
 1    aman     mango with sister    amanzing mango
 2    ramesh   mango via mouth      wow its really good
 3    aman     guava with jimmy     yoyo
 4    ramesh   pineapple            yummy
```

Now i want a single query where i can fetch those rows who is having common `eating value (table name eating)` for example where name is aman and ramesh who is having same eating then show the rows

```
    info
    -----
     id   name     eating     andSaying
     ---  ----     ------     ---------
      1    aman     mango with sister    amanzing mango
      2    ramesh   mango via mouth      wow its really good
```

i have tried this query but it is NOT Working

```
SELECT * 
FROM info a1
JOIN info a2
  ON a1.name!= a2.name
  AND a1.eating (get first array before "space"mango ) = a2.eating(get first array before "space" mango )
```

How to get the two rows if eating on first letter is same?

it should reflect two rows like this

```
  info
        -----
         id   name     eating     andSaying
         ---  ----     ------     ---------
          1    aman     mango with sister    amanzing mango
          2    ramesh   mango via mouth      wow its really good
```

Comment: What if there's another couple eating the same thing? Should those people be returned as well?

Comment: yes exactly ....

Comment: Your effort looks pretty close. DISTINCT with a simple join will suffice.

Comment: *if eating on first letter is same* ... I think you mean first *word*, is that right?

Comment: ohh ya sorry, that is correct first word like "mango"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the `eating` values related to more than one `name` values you can use:

```
SELECT eating
FROM info
GROUP BY eating
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
```

Output:

```
eating
------
mango
```

Use the above query as a derived table and join back to the `info` table to get the expected result set:

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM info AS i1
JOIN (
    SELECT eating
    FROM info
    GROUP BY eating
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1   
) AS i2 ON i1.eating = i2.eating
```

**Edit:**

To get matches depending on the first *word* of `eating` field, instead of:

```
GROUP BY eating
```

use:

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`eating`, ' ', 1)
```

So the whole query could look like this:

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM info AS i1
JOIN (
   SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`eating`, ' ', 1) AS eating
   FROM info
   GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`eating`, ' ', 1)
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `name`) > 1
) AS i2 ON i1.eating LIKE CONCAT(i2.eating, '%');
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/JUH76816)

Comment: How to get the two rows if only first letter is same in eating value?

Comment: actually its wokrking fine but it is not giving me result in alternate order on name .. 
it is giving the result by grounping name like (aman,abc,xys)(aman,abz,xys)/(aman,abh,xys)/(aman,abz,xys) then the second name is coming (ramesh,abc sd,....)/(ramesh,abx sd,/...)/(ramesh,abh sd,....) (ramesh,abz sd,...)..........cant name be in alternate order?

Comment: @doe You to use `ORDER BY` to determine the order.

Answer (score 0):

I've stripped out the irrelevant parts of the problem...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,eating VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(name,eating)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('aman','mango'),
('ramesh','mango'),
('aman','guava'),
('ramesh','pineapple');

SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.name <> x.name 
            AND y.eating = x.eating;
+--------+--------+
| name   | eating |
+--------+--------+
| ramesh | mango  |
| aman   | mango  |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: How to get the two rows if only first letter is same in eating value?

Comment: @doe This is a radically different question from that originally asked. I would suggest that you undo your edit, and ask a fresh question, referencing this one.